# Biostatistics and Pure

Tags: biostatistics

I hope this is not "opinion" question

but I am curious as to whether or not the study of statistics and probability theory in the realm of cancer genomics is considered "less philosophical" than the pure math studies.

I am only asking because something inside me is very skeptical of pure math, i.e.  algebra and geometry.  I just am lacking a faith to study these abstract notions.

but I am interested in modeling cancer genes, and using probability to study biology.

however, I have some ingrained notion that "applied" is not as respected as "pure" math.  Can someone help me with this?

Even my algebra teacher has scoffed at applied studies.  So I am having this dilemma.

For instance,  straying away from functional analysis, and moving more into probability theory seems to me like a "weaker" move.   I am sure this is a philosophical question, but I am looking for the guidance of those working in statistics, and biostatistics.   Are these field theoretically rewarding and dense?

Ultimately,
 my question is that ,  do you think that biostatistics is only a particular scope on a specific part of biotechnology revolution? Do you think biostats is a general field, or particular and why?   "

The reason I am concerned about this, is because I am not interested in studying just a narrow field interested in just a small set of problems, and wish to be as general as possible.  Can someone advise on this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This question seems pretty solidly in the realm of *opinion*.

Comment: how can we know if a field is not general enough?

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Setting out to tackle (& *identify*) general, broadly applicable problems without ever having solved a specific problem in a narrow field might be viewed as a little ambitious. ["A Conversation with Sir David Cox", *Statist. Sci*, **9**, 3](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1177010394) is interesting - his "fantastic experience" at the start of his career with the Wool Industries Research Association.

Comment: I think this question could be rephrased to be more appropriate for this site. Maybe something simple like "what distinguishes biostats from 'vanilla' stats?"

Comment: The conversation with David Cox is exactly what I wanted to read.  THANK YOU. I am interested not just in the interior of a field (i.e. "I study stats")  I am interested in the exterior of the field (i.e.  Wool textiles intersects physics, biology, engineering, and economic government funding etc etc )

Comment: He mentions in the paper that the statistics jobs in the UK for academy were all going to the Pure mathematicians.  is this true today?

Comment: In the paper of "Conversation with Sir David Cox" he mentions exactly the limits with applied fields being narrow in scope , and the broad sense of theoretical development.  Can studying biostatistics fall into the category of being "narrow" in scope?  and does biostats have the capacity to be broad enough to expand statistical theory in general?  this is my ultimate question.

Comment: (1) Hes' talking about Maths posts - Statistics posts barely existed back then. (2) It's more nuanced than a choice between narrowly applicable applied work vs broadly applicable theoretical work. Cox says his theoretical work on conditional inference "was very strongly motivated by practical experience  and yet on the other hand, I couldn't say it arose from one particular special type of problem. It arose in a sense from all the applied work I'd done to that point."

Answer (score 2):

I see theory and application as intimately tied together.

Without theory we don't really *know* anything, and without application we don't know *about* anything.

Application without theory devolves into stamp-collecting, and theory without any application* is some kind of abstract language-game.

* Without application, what is it actually *for*? Keeping mathematicians out of pubs?
Fortunately, even when people do try to do purely abstract mathematics, the kind that is treated as 'interesting' is also the kind people keep coming up with applications for.

Theory gives a framework and methodology for understanding how to solve real problems (without which you are unlikely to get far), and application gives real problems to solve.

While I see myself as primarily an applied-applied statistician who has a smattering of theory, I can't imagine doing much of either without the other. Tools like simulation can get you some way where theory isn't up to the task (or our abilities aren't), but even simulation relies on theory. Almost everything I do relies on theoretical concepts, to frame and guide what I am doing, even when I seem to be doing the most "applied" things. My first step in trying to think about a new problem involves a pen and some paper (or sometimes, effective equivalents like LaTeX), typically to do algebra related to the statistical problem.

Comment: Can your work in the applied area, lead to the develop of new theory?  or is studying applied problems, trapping you into this particular problem set?

Comment: Or to be more concrete,  do the journals published in the statistical journals come from Math PhD's  or from Statistics PhDs?

Comment: Well, my PhD is in statistics (at least that's how I'd characterize it); but plenty of people publishing statistics papers have neither a mathematics PhD nor a stats one - I can point to many people from other areas doing important work in stats. (Indeed, people manage to publish good work just fine with no PhD at all; Fisher didn't seem to require one, for example, yet he did major work in more than one area. There's really nothing special about a PhD. It's basically a sign that you can do publishable work. Anyone with a couple of half-decent papers has demonstrated that already.)

Comment: wow this Fisher gentleman , quite awesome.  Yes, I think the limitations that I am worried about is not dependent on the field but on ability. It is quite possible to study statistics and publish in biology.  and vice versa.

Comment: In you applied work, you use theory, but can you develop theory?

Comment: or do only Pure math guys develop theory?